# DIsplaying NULL Value with PHP in HTML

Tags: php, html, oracle

I was trying to use PHP to display my data in a HTML . However, it does not really fetch the NULL value from the database. For example, I tried to used->load(); function to display the value it worked. But it only worked for the fields with values. When the Field is with NULL values, the program stopped.

Here is my script as below. can anybody help me out? I really appreciate it!

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>SR Update</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form  action="php_oracle_update3.php?CusID=<?=$_GET["CusID"];?>"  name="frmEdit" method="post">  
<?php 
$db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.06.82.71)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)))";
$objConnect = ocilogon("testUser123","****",$db); 

if($objConnect)
    echo "Connection succeded <br>";
else
{
    echo "Connection failed";

}

$strSQL = "SELECT OBJECTID, FROM_,DEPT,ROOM, CONTACT,PHONE,PROJECT,FIELDSUP,TYPE FROM SR2 WHERE OBJECTID =  '".$_GET["CusID"]."' ";  
$objParse = oci_parse ($objConnect, $strSQL);  
oci_execute ($objParse,OCI_DEFAULT);  


$objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse,OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS);  


if($objResult !=false)  
{ 

?>

<table width="600" border="1">  
<tr>  
<th width="91"> <div align="center">ID  </div></th>  
<th width="160"> <div align="center">FROM  </div></th>  
<th width="198"> <div align="center">DEPARTMENT  </div></th>  
<th width="97"> <div align="center">ROOM  </div></th>  
<th width="70"> <div align="center">CONTACT  </div></th>  
<th width="70"> <div align="center">PHONE  </div></th>  
<th width="70"> <div align="center">PROJECT  </div></th>  
<th width="70"> <div align="center">FIELDSUP </div></th>  

</tr>  
<tr>  
<td><div align="center"><input type="text"  name="txtObjectID" size="5"  value="<?=$objResult["OBJECTID"];?>"></div></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="txtFrom" size="12"  value="<?=$objResult["FROM_"]->load();?>"></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="txtDepartment" size="12"  value="<?=$objResult["DEPT"]->load();?>"></td>  
<td><div align="center"><input type="text"  name="txtRoom" size="5"  value="<?=$objResult["ROOM"]->load();?>"></div></td>  
<td align="center"><input type="text" name="txtContact" size="10"  value="<?=$objResult["CONTACT"]->load();?>"></td>  
<td align="center"><input type="text" name="txtPhone" size="10"  value="<?=$objResult["PHONE"];?>"></td>  
<td align="center"><input type="text" name="txtProject" size="7"  value="<?=$objResult["PROJECT"]->load();?>"></td> 
<td align="center"><input type="text" name="txtFieldsup" size="7" value="<?=$objResult["FIELDSUP"];?>"></td> 


</tr>  
</table>  
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">  


<?php   


}  
else
{

echo "Not found OBJECTID=".$_GET["CusID"];  

}  

oci_close($objConnect);  
?>


</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: I think oci_fetch_array return an array empy or not. Then $objResult always return true. Try if(count($objResult))

Comment: Thanks for the reply Emeeus! I tried but did not really work. :(

Comment: Null is a state, not a value. Stopped? Are you getting any error? Not clear what exact issue is.

Comment: When I use value="<?=$objResult["FIELDSUP"];?>, it did not really display the values in the field. However, When I use value="<?=$objResult["PHONE"]->load();?>">, the field with values are displayed but the field with NULL will stop the program. and submit button does not show up on the HTML interface.

Comment: Try : value="<?=isset($objResult["PHONE"]->load()) ? $objResult["PHONE"]->load() : '';?>">

Comment: Which fields get null values and what would you consider a "default" value for each of them?

Comment: value="<?=isset($objResult["FIELDSUP"]);?>" works for me. Could anybody explain why?

Comment: [FIELDSUP] is the default field that I am working on and the data type is string.

Comment: Actually when I used "isset" in value="<?=isset($objResult["FIELDSUP"]);?> , it returns 1 for field with NULL.